# MVC CheckBoxFor causing unobtrusive validation to be bypassed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox, unobtrusive-validation

I have a form containing a number of controls - nothing fancy:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <fieldset>
        <legend>EmployeeViewModel</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee.Title)
etc.....
```

**UPDATE**
My ViewModel:

```
public class EmployeeCreateViewModel
    {
        public EmployeeCreateModel Employee { get; set; }
..etc
```

My Employee model:

```
public class EmployeeCreateModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Job Title")]
        [Required]
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }

        public bool Active { get; set; }
...etc
```

**The Problem** - I am using unobtrusive validation which works fine UNTIL I add a checkbox to the form. Regardless of the checkbox state, the form is submitted, bypassing client-side validation and errors are caught by the server-side validation.  This is my checkbox:

```
<div class="editor-label">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.Active)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Employee.Active)
</div>
```

The checkbox model property is not a required field, so it doesn't need to be validated and I can see that it has a valid True/False value when it reaches the controller method.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: So you don't want it to say false in the controller if it's unchecked?

Comment: @Andrew - the value passed to the controller IS false if it's unchecked

Comment: @markpsmith what errors are being caught by the server-side validation?  Just because the checkbox has a value when it's unchecked doesn't mean it's being validated.  It's just how checkboxes work in MVC.  A bool has to be True or False, so when it's unchecked False is correct.

Comment: @Andrew - the checkbox is NOT one of the errors caught server-side, but I'm not interested in validating it anyway.

Comment: Can I just clarify - you're saying that when you add the checkbox to the form all client-side validation for the whole form is bypassed, and when you remove the checkbox, client-side validation works again?

Comment: @whoshotjr - that's correct. The client-side validation shows for a second while the form is posted, then the page refreshes & the server-side validation shows

Comment: Looks like others have had a similar problem. This question has no answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415655/unobtrusive-validation-not-working-after-adding-checkboxes-to-the-form-in-mvc-4

Comment: @whoshotjr - good find. I've answered that question with my workaround but I'd still like to find out the cause of the problem.

Comment: Found another one as well - you may as well answer that too! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391025/unobtrusive-validation-fails-when-a-checkbox-is-on-the-form

Comment: @whoshotjr - that would just be greedy!  I've posted a link in the comments instead. cheers.

Comment: Same problem here.  I noticed that by default, it adds the data-val-required and data-val attributes to the checkbox by default.  When those are there, the problems you describe happen.  When I remove them using the inspector, the form validates as desired.  In summary, it looks like CheckBoxFor adds the required attributes automatically.

Answer (score 3):

First, open javascript console (e.g., chrome inspector panel) and see if you are getting **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'** error from jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js.

If you are seeing this error, you are probably using jquery 1.9.x or higher. If you check "Preserve log upon navigation" (chrome), you can see an error saying "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u**".

To solve this problem, include jquery migrate 1.2.x after jquery 1.9.x.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

For details, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609565/parsejson-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u).